# Save TableViewer Data into properties file

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

How can I save the `TableViewer` data into a properties file and populate the same data when reopening the `TableViewer`?

```
private void buildWellBoreDate(
            NearWellBoreModellingData nearWellBoreModellingData, Properties p) {
            List<DownholeComplexityTable> downhole=modelProviderDownholeComplexityTable.INSTANCE.getDownholeComplexityTables();
            for(int i=0;i<downhole.size();i++){
                p.setProperty("row"+i+"."+"NameofZones",((DownholeComplexityTable)downhole).getNameOfZones());
            }

            String fieldNameWell = nearWellBoreModellingData.getFieldNameWell();
            if (fieldNameWell != null) {
                p.setProperty(KEY_FIELDNAME_NEARWELL, fieldNameWell);
            }

while trying this way I am able to save the textfield data but getting error for the table java.lang.ClassCastException:
```

Comment: Why don't you use an SQLite database? Seems to be the more appropriate choice.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself that we can help with?  Generally the responses you get are going to be more helpful if you can show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But its project requirement to add the table values in file like row1 then value1,value 2